# MeshCat simulator not loading models

Tags: drake

I have been using Drake on google colab for a bit over a month, but suddenly the MeshCat simulator stopped displaying models. Everything runs fine (there are no error messages), when we click on the link, we only see the origin point with the colored xyz axes. We tried running the tutorials from the Robotic Manipulation course using Drake, https://manipulation.csail.mit.edu/clutter.html#example1, but we run into the same problem. I added a picture of what the code returns, and what the MeshCat simulator displays.

[image]
[image: what MeshCat displays]

Comment: It seems that ngrok changed their model / limits for the free tier.  I will have to look into resolving this.

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/issues/146 to track the issue and the resolution.  This is a bad one.  I think meshcat on colab is broken until it's resolved.